# Click event firing on clicking onto div's border

Tags: javascript, css

I want that after putting input values and clicking onto the check icon, check icon should get replaced with the edit icon but it only works when you click the check icon's border but not the whole icon.

```html
<div class="mainContainer">
  <h1 class="heading">Details Collector</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="items">
      <label class="label" for="Name">Name :</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input class="text" type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div class="items">
      <label class="label" for="State">State :</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input class="text" type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div class="items">
      <label class="label" for="Country">Country :</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input class="text" type="text"/>
    </div>
        
    <div class="check-icon icons mainicon">
      <i class="fa fa-check " aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
          
    <div class="edit-icon icons hidden mainicon">
      <i class="far fa-edit " aria-hidden="true"></i> 
    </div>
    
    <div class="plus-icon icons ">
      <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

js fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/p6bgf5kx/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to bind two click events. you can achieve using single click event.

```js
const container = document.querySelector(".container");

// Creating a SPAN element and appending it to div
container.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target.closest(".icons");
  if (tgt) {
    if (tgt.classList.contains("swapped")) return; // stop
    if (tgt.classList.contains("check-icon")) {
      tgt.classList.add("swapped");
      let texts = document.querySelectorAll(".text");
      let items = document.querySelectorAll(".items");
      texts.forEach((text, i) => {
        let span = document.createElement("span");
        let val = document.createTextNode(text.value ? text.value : "");
        span.appendChild(val);
        span.classList.add("text2");
        items[i].appendChild(span);
        if (text.value) text.value = ""; // setting the input value to empty once clicked onto the check button
        text.parentNode.replaceChild(span, text);
        
        let btns = document.querySelectorAll(".mainicon");
  if (tgt.classList.contains("check-icon")) {
    Array.from(btns).forEach((ele) => {
      ele.classList.toggle("hidden");
    });
  }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.mainContainer {
  height: 400px;
  width: 900px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 200px auto;
  border: 5px solid black;
  border-radius: 8px;
}
.heading {
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
}

.container {
  width: 840px;
  height: auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 230px 230px 230px 50px 50px 50px;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  top: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #007bff;
}

.items {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
}

.text {
  width: 130px;
}

.icons {
  font-size: 18px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  margin-left: 12px;
  color: #007bff;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.icons:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #007bff;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css"
      integrity="sha512-Fo3rlrZj/k7ujTnHg4CGR2D7kSs0v4LLanw2qksYuRlEzO+tcaEPQogQ0KaoGN26/zrn20ImR1DfuLWnOo7aBA=="
      crossorigin="anonymous"
      referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
    />
  </head>
  <body style="background-color: #007bff">
    <div class="mainContainer">
      <h1 class="heading">Details Collector</h1>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="items">
          <label class="label" for="Name">Name :</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input class="text" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div class="items">
          <label class="label" for="State">State :</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input class="text" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div class="items">
          <label class="label" for="Country">Country :</label> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
          <input class="text" type="text"/>
        </div>

    
        <div class="check-icon icons mainicon">
          <i class="fa fa-check " aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
      
      <div class="edit-icon icons hidden mainicon">
        <i class="far fa-edit " aria-hidden="true"></i> 
      </div>


        <div class="plus-icon icons ">
          <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add event onclick in button check of row.
In HTML code, you should replace the source code as below. You can convert "1" to sequence numbers when using loops.

```
<div class="check-icon icons mainicon" id="btn_check_1" onclick="clickCheckInRow(this)">
          <i class="fa fa-check " aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
      <div class="edit-icon icons hidden mainicon" id="btn_edit_1">
        <i class="far fa-edit " aria-hidden="true"></i> 
      </div>
        <div class="plus-icon icons">
          <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
</div>
```

In JS, you should delete this source code

```
container.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const ran = e.target;
  let btns = document.querySelectorAll(".mainicon");
  if (ran.classList.contains("check-icon")) {
    Array.from(btns).forEach((ele) => {
      ele.classList.toggle("hidden");
    });
  }
});
```

and replace it with the source code below.

```
function clickCheckInRow(that){
  let btn_edit_id = that.id.replace("btn_check", "btn_edit");
  document.getElementById(btn_edit_id).classList.remove("hidden");
  document.getElementById(that.id).classList.add("hidden");
}
```

It worked for me!!! You can try it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/longut/n1k9mtv8/7/)